# Derivative of a vector: how to compute it and how it is related to Hessian matrix of each $F_i$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be of class $C^\infty$.

I am trying to solve this exercise from my calculus class: Let $s\in\mathbb{R}$ and compute
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \left(\sum_{j=1}^3 \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_j}(s y), \sum_{j=1}^3 \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x_j}(s y), \sum_{j=1}^3 \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial x_j}(s y)\right),$$
where $y=(y_1, y_2, y_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3$.

As I am not sure how to proceed, I am starting considering the term
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_j}(s y).$$
I think it should be $\frac{\partial^2 F_1}{\partial x_1 x_k}$ with $k=2, 3$, i.e. the first column of the Hessian matrix of $F_1$. Anyway, even if this was correct, I don't know how to upgrade to the more challenging case considered the given exercise.

Could someone please help? How the result is related to the Hessian matrix of each component $F_i$? Thank you.

Comment: You can differentiate componentwise, so your idea is easily extended to the "more challenging" case.

Comment: Is $x$ any vector, or is it a $\alpha(1,1,1)$ vector for some real number $\alpha$?

Comment: Here $x$ is any vector.

Comment: You are using the same notation for the components of the vector $x$ and for partial differentials. Please write your vector differently, f.i. $x = (y_1,y_2,y_3)$ and rewrite your question in this new notation. Then I will be able to help you.

Comment: Note that there is no "Hessian of $F$", since it's not a scalar function. Only Hessians of its component functions exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_j}(s y) = \sum_{i=1}^3 y_i\frac{\partial^2 F_1}{\partial x_i x_j}$$
Thus:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \left(\sum_{j=1}^3 \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_j}(s y)\right) = \text{sum of components of  vector }y*H_1 = y*H_1*(1,1,1)^T$$ where $H_1$ is the Hessian of $F_1$.
Now proceed by computing your original derivative componentwise.

Comment: Do you want me to write the remaining computations explicitly, or is this enough?

Comment: Jkbb I'd prefer you to write what remains and, if possibile, to highlight the relation with the Hessian matrix of each component.